# DateTime parse problem using JDK 17 (oracle). Bug?

Tags: java, datetimeformatter, java-17

Upgrading my Java environment to Java 17 (oracle64-17.0.1) from Java 11 (openjdk64-11.0.2), running on MacOS, I got an unexpected date format parsing error. To test this I wrote a short java program which I then compiled and ran under each environment.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.UK);
        for (String month : List.of("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")) {
            String dateStr = "26 " + month + " 2021";
            try {
                LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, formatter);
                System.out.println(dateStr + " OK [" + ld.toString() + "]");
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                System.out.println(dateStr + " FAILED DateTimeParseException");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output from running under both environments:

```
~/work/jenv $jenv global openjdk64-11.0.2
~/work/jenv $java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
~/work/jenv $javac Main.java
~/work/jenv $java Main
26 Jan 2021 OK [2021-01-26]
26 Feb 2021 OK [2021-02-26]
26 Mar 2021 OK [2021-03-26]
26 Apr 2021 OK [2021-04-26]
26 May 2021 OK [2021-05-26]
26 Jun 2021 OK [2021-06-26]
26 Jul 2021 OK [2021-07-26]
26 Aug 2021 OK [2021-08-26]
26 Sep 2021 OK [2021-09-26]
26 Oct 2021 OK [2021-10-26]
26 Nov 2021 OK [2021-11-26]
26 Dec 2021 OK [2021-12-26]
~/work/jenv $jenv global oracle64-17.0.1
~/work/jenv $java -version
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
~/work/jenv $javac Main.java
~/work/jenv $java Main
26 Jan 2021 OK [2021-01-26]
26 Feb 2021 OK [2021-02-26]
26 Mar 2021 OK [2021-03-26]
26 Apr 2021 OK [2021-04-26]
26 May 2021 OK [2021-05-26]
26 Jun 2021 OK [2021-06-26]
26 Jul 2021 OK [2021-07-26]
26 Aug 2021 OK [2021-08-26]
26 Sep 2021 FAILED DateTimeParseException
26 Oct 2021 OK [2021-10-26]
26 Nov 2021 OK [2021-11-26]
26 Dec 2021 OK [2021-12-26]
```

The exception message is as follows:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '26 Sep 2021' could not be parsed at index 3
```

I find it hard to believe there is a bug in the JDK, so am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output are you getting from `LocalDate.of(2021, Month.SEPTEMBER, 26).format(formatter)` on your Java 17? My guess is `26 Sept 2021`.

Comment: Indeed, it is `26 Sept 2021`. I just tested with "Temurin-17+35" JDK.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69267710/septembers-short-form-sep-no-longer-parses-in-java-17-in-en-gb-locale