# Parsing DateTime with different Locales gives two different Instants

Tags: java, java-time

I'm trying to parse a date with three Locales: UK, US, ENGLISH.

```
 String s = "Mon Sep 12 00:02:16 BST 2022";
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = null;
 String pattern = "E MMM dd H:m:s z yyyy";
 formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withLocale(Locale.UK);
 System.out.println("UK: " + Instant.from(formatter.parse(s)));
 formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withLocale(Locale.US);
 System.out.println("US: " + Instant.from(formatter.parse(s)));
 formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
 System.out.println("EN: " + Instant.from(formatter.parse(s)));
```

Result:

```
UK: 2022-09-11T23:02:16Z
US: 2022-09-11T13:02:16Z
EN: 2022-09-11T13:02:16Z
```

UK is correct. Both US and ENGLISH are wrong. Why?

Edit : test was made on Windows 10. openjdk 11.

Comment: Locale in this instance means "parse the text according to the language conventions of that country", not "parse the text according to the timezone of that country". The zone in all 3 cases is BST - British Summer Time. You might, for example, want to parse a date written in French (Monday = Lundi) representing a date in a British timezone.

Comment: @Michael The US and EN outputs show a *different* time (1pm instead of 11pm).

Comment: What is the "correct" time zone of US?? ;) ..And what is the "correct" time zone of "English"?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Missed it, but cannot reproduce. On my machine, jdk8.0.275, the output is the same in all 3 cases.

Comment: ..answer: it is ambiguous

Comment: ..whereas "UK" covers one single time zone!(?)

Comment: @xerx593 See my comment further up.

Comment: Strange: if I run this on JDK 17, the first case fails with a parse exception. For UK, the parser for some reason expects "Sept" instead of "Sep" (apparently that is how the British abbreviate September). But when I fix that, it returns the same result for all three cases.

Comment: @Jesper https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69267710/septembers-short-form-sep-no-longer-parses-in-java-17-in-en-gb-locale/69268271#69268271

Comment: Suspect your problem is that BST is parsing to Bourgainville Standard Time, not British Standard Time. "BST" is ambiguous. Cannot account for the output being different between the 3 cases. I'm assuming a transcription error or something. Doesn't seem possible. `ZonedDateTime.from(formatter.parse(s)).getZone() = Pacific/Bougainville`

Comment: BST may, as a third possibility, be parsed as Bangladesh Standard Time. I don’t know whether there are still more possibilities.